# OroPlatform: disable particular checkbox in datagrid

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

Is there an option to disable particular checkbox in datagrid based on some condition (for example: if product is Out of Stock), and exclude it from Mass action?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually, It's not clear when to disable checkboxes because some actions might be allowed for specific rows and others are not.

Instead of disabling, we allow checking any line but don't process those that are not allowed. And print the list or just a count of not processed items in the result message.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a way to do this with Oro 5.1.4's shopping list frontend datagrid.

In the frontend shopping list's line item datagrid, it uses a html template to render the select checkbox located below:
`vendor/oro/commerce/src/Oro/Bundle/ShoppingListBundle/Resources/public/templates/datagrid/cell/select-row-cell.html`

In order to override it you need to copy this HTML template to your custom bundle with the same path starting from Resources folder. Then in your `jsmodules.yml` you need to tell Oro to use your custom HTML template when ever it calls for that template.

For example:

```
map:
    oroshoppinglist/js/datagrid/cell/select-row-cell:
        oroshoppinglist/templates/datagrid/cell/select-row-cell.html: yourcustombundlename/templates/datagrid/cell/select-row-cell.html
```

In the HTML template itself, if `obj._isKitItemLineItem` is true then it would render no checkbox, so I updated that condition to include an || (or) to add a second condition.

```
<% if (obj._isKitItemLineItem || 2nd condition here ) { %>
    <span class="checkbox-label cell-checkbox no-gap" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="checkbox-placeholder">
            <span class="cell-line" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
<% } else { %>
    <label class="checkbox-label cell-checkbox no-gap">
        <input type="checkbox" data-role="select-row-cell" class="select-row-cell-input" <% if (checked) { %> checked="checked"<% } %>>
        <span class="cell-line" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only"><%- _.__('oro.datagrid.action.select_row') %></span>
    </label>
<% } %>
```

If you want to update the obj to include more data into it, then you'll need to create a datagrid event listener for that specific datagrid (in this case it would be `frontend-customer-user-shopping-list-edit-grid`.
And tag the event listener as below in your YML file.

```
- { name: kernel.event_listener, event: oro_product.datagrid_line_items_data.frontend-customer-user-shopping-list-edit-grid, method: methodNameHere }
```

Then in your method, you just use the `$event` object to add data.

```
foreach ($event->getLineItems() as $lineItem) {
    $lineItemId = $lineItem->getEntityIdentifier();
    event->addDataForLineItem($lineItemId, ['extraDataName' => $dataValue]);
}
```

You'll also want to update the datagrid itself in `datagrids.yml` to include this new property.

```
datagrids:
    frontend-customer-user-shopping-list-edit-grid:
        properties:
            extraDataName: ~
```